# Is "otaku" a male term?

Tags: word-choice

I want to determine if the term is gender specific. Thank you.

Comment: I personally don't think so, for me it's unisex but, In the western there is a term for girls which is "otome". Just keep in mind that in japan it might be different, even the connotation of the word Otaku is very different in western and in japan

Comment: @FelipeOliveira As far as I'm aware, 'otome' doesn't refer to a female otaku in the west; rather, it refers to 乙女ゲーム.

Comment: @Nothingatall In brazil it was often used by girls who wanted to distinguish from male otaku, I just looked it up, in US it doesn't but in Brazil it does lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. There are many female otaku, too. Among those who understand the modern otaku culture, otaku is a fairly gender-neutral term. For example, about 35% of attendees of [Comiket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comiket) are female.

That said, otaku is a slang word [with a relatively long and complicated history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku#Etymology), and it used to have a very derogatory and narrow meaning. I imagine there are still many people who believe otaku-like hobby is only for males.